# Transfering data from an activity to another and recomposing the name of varibles

Tags: android, tags, bundle

I have menu Menu 1 containing 20 buttons bt1, bt2,..btn when you click a button should go to the main activity Main1 where a title and a text should be displayed. Main1 is extended to Text1 where the titles and texts are.
What's needed is that when you click on button2 for example the Main1 should display Title2 and Text2 and so on.
I did this in the Menu 1:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
            //do common code here
             Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();

                bundle1.putString("somekey1", act1);
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main1.class);
                i.putExtras(bundle1);
                startActivity(i);

                str= v.getResources().getResourceName(v.getId());
                act1= Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(str.substring(str.indexOf("bt")+2 )));
```

in the Main1 I did this:

```
num = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getExtras().getString("somekey1"));


stringId1 = getResources().getIdentifier("title"+num, "string", getPackageName());
    stringId2 = getResources().getIdentifier("text"+num, "string", getPackageName());


    if (stringId1 > 0) {
         title=getString(stringId1);
          text2=getString(stringId2);
    }
```

in the Text1 I did this:

```
public class Text extends Activity {    
public String

title1="some title",
text1="some text",

title2="some title",
text2="some text",

titl3="333",
tex3="kar3",

title4="xxxxx",
text4="xxxxx",

title5="",
text5="",
```

But all of that doesn't work, and about to shake my head on the wall, as the bundle doesn't transfer the data, and `stringId1 = getResources().getIdentifier("title"+num, "string", getPackageName());`
also returns 0.

Help please`

Comment: Instead of creating a bundle object.. You can directly send the value in the intent and I guess it will work. I think you have to use i.putExtra

Comment: how to do that, I'm really getting tired?

Comment: There are a couple of ways to achieve this. Instead of creating a bundle, you can call [putExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra) on the intent before you start the activity.
Or you can save the string in [SharedPreferences()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and get it in the new activity

Comment: Just remove creation of bundle.. After intent declaration.. Use i.putExtra("somekey1", act1);

Answer (score 1):

Pass the intent as shown below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main1.class);
        intent.putExtra("Key1", "Value1");
        intent.putExtra("Key2", "Value2");
        startActivity(intent);
```

And in the oncreate() of your Main1.class :

```
Intent dataIntent = getIntent();
    String value1 = dataIntent.getStringExtra("Key1");
    String value2 = dataIntent.getStringExtra("Key2");
```

Comment: yes it's working but why  this code return always 0: getResources().getIdentifier("titl"+num, "string", getPackageName());

Comment: Would you please call this [act1= Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(str.substring(str.indexOf("bt")+2 )));] before starting Activity?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
            //do common code here
             Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();

                str= v.getResources().getResourceName(v.getId());
                act1= Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(str.substring(str.indexOf("bt")+2 )));

                bundle1.putString("somekey1", act1);
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main1.class);
                i.putExtras(bundle1);
                startActivity(i);
```